# What is the C++ feature being used in this Nana demo code?

Tags: c++11, nana

On [their webpage](http://www.nanapro.org/en-us/), the Nana GUI people give this example:

```
#include<nana/gui.hpp>

int main()
{
     using namespace nana;
     form fm;
     drawing{fm}.draw([](paint::graphics& graph){
         graph.string({10, 10}, L"Hello, world!", colors::red);
     });
     fm.events().click(API::exit);
     fm.show();
     exec();
}
```

What is the C++ feature that is being used in the line that starts: drawing{fm}.draw...

I have never seen {} used like that.

Comment: Thinking about readability. Yeah, I *can* read (and understand) it. But doing so I also stumbled a bit in the line `drawing{fm}...`. You are not alone, Scooter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called uniform initialization, and was added in C++11. See e.g. [Bjarne's page](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init) for more info.

In your particular example, an unnamed instance of `drawing` is constructed with `fm` as the actual parameter to `drawing`'s constructor. The `draw` method is then invoked on this `drawing` instance. This could also have been written using normal parens:

```
drawing(fm).draw([](paint::graphics& graph){
     graph.string({10, 10}, L"Hello, world!", colors::red);
 });
```

With a few minor differences: namely that using `{}` would favor a constructor that takes an `initializer_list` (if such a constructor exists); using `{}` avoids the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse); and using `{}` avoids implicit lossy narrowing of arguments. See [this GotW](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/) for more details.

Comment: So a temporary or unnamed "drawing" object is being constructed, and the constructor is passed the fm variable and then that new object is having it's draw() function called. Is that correct?